# networkReady="NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Network plugin returns error: cni plugin not initialized"

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to install Kubernetes cluster on Ubuntu VPS 20.04. I followed the lowing steps for setup:

```
sudo adduser kubernetes
sudo apt-get install vim
sudo apt-get install net-tools
swapoff -a
Remove following line from /etc/fstab
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0

sudo apt update
sudo apt install docker.io
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo systemctl enable docker

sudo apt install apt-transport-https curl
curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add
echo "deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" >> ~/kubernetes.list
sudo mv ~/kubernetes.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d
sudo apt update
sudo apt install kubeadm kubelet kubectl kubernetes-cni

sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16

sudo mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

After I run the commands I get:

```
kubernetes@ubuntu1:~$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE     NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP              NODE      NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-system   coredns-6d4b75cb6d-bffgt          0/1     Pending   0          6m42s   <none>          <none>    <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-6d4b75cb6d-t4wmv          0/1     Pending   0          6m42s   <none>          <none>    <none>           <none>
kube-system   etcd-ubuntu1                      1/1     Running   0          6m53s   192.168.1.113   ubuntu1   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-apiserver-ubuntu1            1/1     Running   0          6m53s   192.168.1.113   ubuntu1   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-ubuntu1   1/1     Running   0          6m53s   192.168.1.113   ubuntu1   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-cxpcl                  1/1     Running   0          6m42s   192.168.1.113   ubuntu1   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-scheduler-ubuntu1            1/1     Running   0          6m53s   192.168.1.113   ubuntu1   <none>           <none>
```

I get errors:

```
kubernetes@ubuntu1:~$ journalctl -f
-- Logs begin at Tue 2022-08-09 12:36:16 UTC. --
Aug 09 13:01:55 ubuntu1 systemd[1]: Configuration file /lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service is marked world-inaccessible. This has no effect as configuration data is accessible via APIs without restrictions. Proceeding anyway.
Aug 09 13:01:55 ubuntu1 systemd[1]: Configuration file /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf is marked world-inaccessible. This has no effect as configuration data is accessible via APIs without restrictions. Proceeding anyway.
Aug 09 13:02:00 ubuntu1 kubelet[23126]: E0809 13:02:00.123581   23126 kubelet.go:2349] "Container runtime network not ready" networkReady="NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Network plugin returns error: cni plugin not initialized"
Aug 09 13:02:05 ubuntu1 kubelet[23126]: E0809 13:02:05.127177   23126 kubelet.go:2349] "Container runtime network not ready" networkReady="NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Network plugin returns error: cni plugin not initialized"
Aug 09 13:02:10 ubuntu1 kubelet[23126]: E0809 13:02:10.133037   23126 kubelet.go:2349] "Container runtime network not ready" networkReady="NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Network plugin returns error: cni plugin not initialized"
Aug 09 13:02:15 ubuntu1 kubelet[23126]: E0809 13:02:15.140107   23126 kubelet.go:2349] "Container runtime network not ready" networkReady="NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Network plugin returns error: cni plugin not initialized"
Aug 09 13:02:20 ubuntu1 kubelet[23126]: E0809 13:02:20.144552   23126 kubelet.go:2349] "Container runtime network not ready" networkReady="NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Network plugin returns error: cni plugin not initialized"
Aug 09 13:02:25 ubuntu1 kubelet[23126]: E0809 13:02:25.146070   23126 kubelet.go:2349] "Container runtime network not ready" networkReady="NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Network plugin returns error: cni plugin not initialized"
Aug 09 13:02:30 ubuntu1 kubelet[23126]: E0809 13:02:30.148140   23126 kubelet.go:2349] "Container runtime network not ready" networkReady="NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Network plugin returns error: cni plugin not initialized"
Aug 09 13:02:35 ubuntu1 kubelet[23126]: E0809 13:02:35.150337   23126 kubelet.go:2349] "Container runtime network not ready" networkReady="NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Network plugin returns error: cni plugin not initialized"
Aug 09 13:02:40 ubuntu1 kubelet[23126]: E0809 13:02:40.165866   23126 kubelet.go:2349] "Container runtime network not ready" networkReady="NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Network plugin returns error: cni plugin not initialized"
Aug 09 13:02:45 ubuntu1 kubelet[23126]: E0809 13:02:45.168050   23126 kubelet.go:2349] "Container runtime network not ready" networkReady="NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Network plugin returns error: cni plugin not initialized"
Aug 09 13:02:50 ubuntu1 kubelet[23126]: E0809 13:02:50.171446   23126 kubelet.go:2349] "Container runtime network not ready" networkReady="NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Network plugin returns error: cni plugin not initialized"
```

Do you know how I can fix the issue?

Comment: I haven't used kubeadm but I see that [installing a CNI](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network) is one of the steps. Have you attempted to do that?

Comment: no, it's not installed. let me try

Comment: @PeterPenzov have you resolve this issue ? I'm getting the same on CentOS 8 installing CNI did not worked, I'm not sure what is wrong

Comment: no, I used another plugin for networking.